# React div postions

Tags: reactjs, sass

My HTML looks like following:

```
return (
 <div>
    <If condition={this.state.showFullSizedImage}>

       {/* Main div with full sized background image */}
        <div className="div-one">
        </div>

        {/* Product details div */}
        <If condition={!this.state.showRegistration && !this.state.showLogin}>
         <div className="div-five">

          </div>
         </If>

         {/* Show half page registration */}
          <If condition={this.state.showRegistration}>
              <div className="div-two">

               </div>
          </If>

           {/* Show half page login */}
           <If condition={this.state.showLogin}>
               <div className="div-three">

               </div>
            </If>

            {/* Show half page Password forget */}
            <If condition={this.state.showPwdForgot}>
                <div className="div-four">

                </div>
            </If>
         </If>
        </div>
     );
```

SCSS:

```
.div-one {
  background: url("../../../assets/images/manhattan-min.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
.div-two {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div2 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div2 0.2s forwards;
}
.div-three {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
}
.div-four {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
}

.div-five{
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 250px;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color: brown;
  display: block;

}
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

My div-one should be a full screen div bellow which I should see div-five. There is a button in div-one which when clicked- div-two or div-three or div-four should open to 50% width along with div-one like following:

[image]

Right now div-one, two, three and four render correctly. But div-five can not because of it's and other div's positions do not match.

What should I do?

Comment: Seems more of a css problem than react.

Comment: I put it in react because of this conditional loading of div two, three, four. Only with div one and five it is easier to fix it with positions fixed and relative.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically make div-one width 50% on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will make any difference, but you don't set any width to your .div-five (you set two values for the height).

Since your div is emtpy (in your example code) and has no width, I think it is rendered, but without any width.

But you should be able to see this in your console..

Comment: If I make it's position relative and give top: say 100vh then I can see it but then the problem is: when I scroll down div-one remains fixed and div-five overlaps it